# How to call a smart contract which is located in BSC from a smart contract in the Ethereum mainnet?

Tags: cross-chain

It this possible? How to call a smart contract from a different network? I mean, some cross-chain call. I need a decentralized solution. Chainlink maybe, or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

**It is not possible.** BSC and Ethereum are completely separate blockchains that do not communicate with each others.

Oracles like chainlink have solutions that allow passing data between blockchains, but not directly like you are suggesting. For instance, an oracle operator could read data from an Ethereum smart contract and then push it to a smart contract on BSC with a transaction (that's essentially what chainlink can do). However, this is an indirect process that relies on an intermediary, the oracle operator.