# Is there a way to implement cross chain contract calls

Tags: solidity, polygon

Is there a way to implement cross chain contract calls. Like calling a smart contract function which is on ETHEREUM from a Smart Contract on POLYGON to get data from it.
I knew it's possible to call another contract functions by using interfaces within a same chain.

Comment: It is not possible to do it directly, see https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/106564. It should be possible using an oracle or bridge as intermediary.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to make cross chain contract call, means you want an interoperable smart contract or Blockchain.
When i was in need to do a cross chain call then i make bridge contract worte a worker on and to connect to binance then this worker collect data from binance and send it to our own created blockchain.

https://quant.network/events/the-multi-chain-future-sidechains-layer-2s-and-the-merge/
To unlock the power of blockchain for everyone, by delivering interoperable ecosystems and real-world solutions that simply work: lowering costs, enabling new business and mitigating risk.